# Response to a Terran FE

Tags: starcraft-2

If you either play as Protoss or as Zerg.

**What would be the proper response to a Terran 1 Barrack Expand, if scouted within the first 4 min. For any map type!**

I am looking for hints to what you Protoss and you Zerg, would do.
What would be the correct way to respond.

Comment: Is the Terran wall-ing himself in, and if so, is his wall protecting both his expansion and main, or just his main? This little factoid right here changes everything about how to respond.

Comment: By definition, fast expand would mean they would need to protect their main and expansion.

Comment: A regular 2 depot and 1 barrack block at the main ramp. Followed with 1 bunker at the expo. followed with supply to completely wall off over time.

Comment: @Ender There are pretty much no maps where a Terran can wall himself in at his natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Protoss I see 2 scenarios.

**Expand.**  This is what I do most of the time; throw down my own expansion, and start to tech.  When you do this, keep an eye on the game clock and be ready for Terran to become active with medivacs/drops.

**Aggression**.  This option has become more viable in HotS.  If you see that terran is expanding, you could (grab your second gas if you dont have it already and then) throw down a starport and start making Oracles to pressure.  This option will also leave you minerals to (eventually) grab an expansion of your own.

Answer (score 1):

As Zerg, don't let the Bunker get up without a fight. Keep him up on his main's high ground for as long as possible by bringing Zerglings in at a slow pace: remember that he's producing off of one Barracks and can't possibly match your army strength: he should need 6+ Marines to be able to push down, which means about a dozen Zerglings to force him to get that many. Another option is a Baneling bust off either 1 or 2-base. The crucial part of this is denying scouting by the Terran player with Zerglings, forcing him to guess or use scans to scout. If he tries to build the CC on the low ground and you scout it soon enough, you should easily be able to force a cancel.

As Protoss, 1-gate FE puts you slightly ahead, in my opinion. You can follow it up with a 3-gate  Robo or 3-gate Stargate with upgrades and put pressure on the Terran while taking a pretty fast third.

Alternatively, if you've already planted your Cybernetics Core you can just drop another 2 or 3 Gateways and pressure hard with Stalkers. If you can prevent the bunker from going up, he can't take his expo. If he does so too quickly, he'll need to drop 3 or 4 bunkers to stop your 4-gate.

Comment: Wouldent the bunker already be done before the zerglings can arive in order to cancel it? I mean, as Zerg you would have to 10 pool atleast to reach it. The bunker is up just a few secs. after the barracks are done. And since zerglin speed isnt done at this point, wouldent it be farely easy for terran to hold this off?
IMO both of the toss builds are easily scouted, and should give the terran time to bolster for the assult.

Comment: It entirely depends on the map, and how the terran walls off.

If he walls of his main first, then expands and starts walling of the natural, the bunker will be delayed and lings will have plenty of time. If he goes straight for walling the natural, it's up in the air.

Answer (score 1):

Zerg player here. To give some context, I usually build spawning pool at 14 drones, then expand, and get ling speed asap.

If I scout a Terran building an expansion at the natural, I pump lings and try force a cancel. If forcing a cancel fails, I'll grab a fast third.

If I spot him building an expansion in his main (with an overlord) I will drone for a little bit, and have a pack of lings waiting in his natural for when he tries to fly the expo there. I'll start a baneling nest and stream small packs of lings to the natural, so I can deny this expansion for as long as possible.

If I am able to deny the expo for more than a few minutes, I'll either get swarm hosts, roaches, or mutas into the mix and push the main.

Comment: If the Terran scouts your imidiate third, wouldent that make the Terran put pressure on you since the Terran was able to get the NE up and running. I meen, a quick drop could make it difficult for us on the third!

Comment: Absolutely, that's just the risk I take. Once I get the third up I have to throw an army together ASAP.

Being even on bases in a ZvT is risky, having an economic advantage is huge. Worth the risk.

Comment: So if we work our way into statistcs. Throwing down the third asap on a T FE, gives the Z the best odds?

Comment: I dunno if it's possible to say that statistically, it all depends on how to the Terran is playing.

Comment: If he doesn't get his barracks up fast, it's easier to pump lings and kill him. Then again, if I get my third up faster, it's easier for him to drop harass across 3 bases before I get an army up.

Answer (score 0):

As Zerg, I see two possible responses to terran FE.

- Aggression : get ling speed and banelings asap. You have to kill his expansion command center for it to be worth it. Note that your aggression will be shut down by factory tech, whether it's tank, mines or hellions.
- Take a quick third and proceed into your normal game plan.

As Protoss, I think you HAVE to punish FE from terran if you didn't go for one gate expand or even nexus first. Mules will give them too much of an edge and you will be outnumbered my marines and marauders when he pushes out.

- If you expanded too, proceed into your normal game plan (and don't forget to get AoE units or sentries)
- If you didn't expand, 4 gates or 3 gates + immortal attack will most definitely kill his natural. Then you expand and proceed into teching a bit before crushing him.